# Square covering disk

Tags: geometry, circles

This question comes from TOT Fall 2017 Senior A Level.

> Is it possible to cut the 1 × 1 square into two parts which can cover a disk of
>   diameter greater than 1?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What kind of parts are allowed?  Must they be contiguous, measurable, convex, cuttable by a knife?

Comment: @RossMillikan I think the parts can be anything

Comment: But then the covering of the circle must by rigid motion?  You can certainly cut the corners outside a radius of $1+\epsilon$ off a square and move them to the centers of the sides to make this work, but it is not a rigid motion.  Each corner moves a bit differently.  We need to make the rules clear.

Comment: @RossMillikan Only two parts we can cut, right? I don't get what you are saying. Can you draw a graph? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture below gives a possible answer: the brown piece is cut out of the square and moved to a new position (gray) to cover the two small circle segments lying outside the square.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the rule, each figures never overlap.

Note 1 the number of circles are $1,4,9,16$ is optimal packing. 
[image]

[image]

Those divisions include just circle with diameter 1. Therefore it's impossible.